# "params" doesn't work in Ruby (Sinatra framework)

Tags: ruby, forms, sinatra

I have a simple Sinatra app in which I want to create a form so users can change their number. However, I don't even get as far as changing the number because "params" is not working. Everything is working well. I can see the parameters in the URL but if I print "params" there is nothing but "Echo".

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Application
  register Sinatra::ActiveRecordExtension

  get '/changenumber' do
    p params
    p params[:mynumber]
    p "Echo"
  end
end
```

And a Form:

```
<form action="/changenumber" method="GET">
    Phone: <input type="text" name="mynumber" value="<%= user.number %>">
    <input type="submit" value="Change Number">
</form>
```

Comment: Using GET method for a form might be the reason it doesn't work, you should try changing it to POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [vu-minh-tan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4113965/vu-minh-tan) pointed out you should probably use Post instead of Get.

I rebuild your example and It works well:

```
{"mynumber"=>"test"}
"test"
"echo"
IP - - [TIME] "GET /changenumber?mynumber=test HTTP/1.1" 200 4 0.0005
```

Based on this, I think your problem is that you just lock at the output in your browser. And thats only the last line in your code. You should probably try something like this:

```
get '/changenumber' do
    "Params: #{params} mynumber: #{params[:mynumber]}"
end
```

Comment: I got it too work, thank you. I didn't realize that only the last line will output to the browser.